# PyQT QSqlRelationalDelegate Combobox

Tags: combobox, pyqt, pyqt5, qsqltablemodel

I have a form which has a Qtableview with a QSqlRelationalTableModel.  I would like two of the columns to be read only, one to be a combobox and one to be a spinbox but with a specific range (no negative numbers.)

Out of the box without a QSqlRelationalDelegate, the view works with a combobox automatically on the third column and a spinbox.  In trying to put the validation in the spinbox, I found that it solved my readonly problem on the first two columns.  My only problem is how to correctly implement the combobox on the related field with the foreign key.  I have been able to get a combobox to display but I can't see how to populate the choices from the foreign keys.

How do I populate the combo box?

See the code

```
    def setup_rates_view(self):
        self.rates_model = QSqlRelationalTableModel(self)
        self.rates_model.setTable("rates_stay")
        self.rates_model.setRelation(6, QSqlRelation("rates", "rate_code", "rate_description"))
        self.rates_model.setFilter("id_bookings = '{0}'".format(myapp.res_id))
        self.rates_model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, "Date")
        self.rates_model.setHeaderData(2, Qt.Horizontal, "Basis")
        self.rates_model.setHeaderData(6, Qt.Horizontal, "Code")
        self.rates_model.setHeaderData(4, Qt.Horizontal, "Amount")
        self.rates_model.select()
        self.rates_view = self.ui.rates
        self.rates_view.setModel(self.rates_model)
        self.rates_view.setItemDelegate(QSqlRelationalDelegate(self.rates_view))
        self.rates_view.setColumnHidden(0, True)
        self.rates_view.setColumnHidden(3, True)
        self.rates_view.setColumnHidden(5, True)
        self.rates_view.horizontalHeader().moveSection(4,6)
        self.rates_view.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.rates_view.setItemDelegate(Viewrates(self))

class Viewrates(QSqlRelationalDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QItemDelegate.__init__(self)


    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        if index.column() == 4:
            spinbox = QSpinBox(parent)
            spinbox.setRange(0,10000)
            return spinbox
        elif index.column() == 6:
            combo = QComboBox(parent)
            combo.setModel()
            return combo
```

Comment: `combo = super().createEditor(parent, option, index)`

Comment: I sweated over that for too long.  Now that I see your comment, it's obvious.  (sound of hand slapping forehead.)